# How to efficiently store IP addresses?

Tags: c, array, storage

**Background**
I have a requirement where I need to remove a few nodes in a network based upon a command given by the user. To keep the nodes from transmitting or receiving data I thought of changing its IP address to some other address.  Before I change the address  I want to save the node's IP so that I can re-assign the original IP back to the node after the simulated network outage is over.

My problem is how to efficiently save the nodes' IP addresses. Should I use a linked list or a hash table?

Comment: How efficiently do you need store those IP addresses?  Are you planning to store 20000 of them? Or 20? How about just using a simple array?  p.s. 20k is still a relatively small number

Comment: Could you do it at the underlying system level? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614795/simulate-delayed-and-dropped-packets-on-linux

Comment: There are a zillion other, better, ways to simulate network outages.  Better yet, just down the interface and be done with it.

Comment: Define "efficiently".  Fast for storage?  Fast for retrieval?  Efficient in terms of memory usage?  Does this question actually have anything to do with IP addresses, or are you just asking for a data storage system?

Answer (score 5):

IP(v4) addresses are just four byte long integers presented in a human readable format. You can just store an IP address as an unsigned integer.

Comment: Not to mention that all the netmask arithmetic becomes much easier to do on one big value anyway.

Answer (score 4):

> To keep the nodes from transmitting or receiving data I thought of changing its IP address to some other address.

That is a very dicey solution to your stated problem. You don't need to worry too much about efficiently storing IP Addresses if your solution doesn't involve this sort of hack.

Comment: Might be more appropriate as a comment. As it does not answer the question.